In Multisim, is the IC labeled "SR_FF" active-high or active-low?
I am analyzing the flip flop IC to understand how it works.  Specifically, I am using the chip labeled SR_FF.  I am told that a regular, 4 pin flip flop can either be "active-high" which utilizes NOR gates or "active low" which utilizes NAND gates. So how do I determine whether the SR_FF IC is active-high or active-low?  Neither the Component Detail Report nor the Model Data Report seem to be of any help with respect to this particular question. I have posted this question on the NI forums but received no response.


Do you see the "bubble" on the FF inputs or the "dash"? On SR_FF symbol? If not, you have active-high FF.

I just edited the question to upload the picture.  I don't see any bubbles or dashes. Does that mean it's active-high?

Yes, this is active-high FF. We only see a "bubble" and a "dash" on the not-Q output.  For active low FF you will see "bubble" or "dash" on the inputs as well.

Why don't you plug in some inputs and try just to simulate the circuit? Try active high and active low and see how it behaves?
